# How to Design Appbar like in the Stock Sports App in XAML/C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

[image: Stock Sports App]

I am trying to create the appbar for navigation like the in the stock sports app that comes along with windows 8.  Can anybody please guide me on how to do this in XAML/C# ?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AppBar control is just a container.

You can set Page.BottomAppBar, and Page.TopAppBar properties, with an AppBar control.

Inside this AppBar you can then put (almost) any control you want. Considering what you are trying to achieve, I would suggest creating a custom Button template.

Now, if you want to known how to achieve a specific part of that, you should precise you question. If you don't known where to start, to reproduce this AppBar, I would suggest that you find another exercise to do, before trying to do this.